# Output Rename-Item events to log file

Tags: powershell, file-io, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to log data surrounding the renaming of files using the following script.  The only problem is that the log file contains files that were not renamed due to 'access denied' errors when attempting to rename. I need to figure out how to only create log entries for files that were SUCCESSFULLY renamed or pipe the failed renames to a different log file. I'd also like the total number of files renamed listed at the top of the log file if at all possible(ie 'xxx files were renamed')  I appreciate any suggestions for getting this to work using powershell v2.

```
    $drivesArray = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | select -Expand Root 
foreach ($drive in $drivesArray) {
  Get-ChildItem $drive | Where-Object {
    $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:WinDir}*" -and
    $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:ProgramFiles}*"
  } | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  } | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.Extension -notmatch '^\.(xxx|exe|html)$'
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.FullName + '.xxx';
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName  ($_.FullName + '.xxx')  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Add-Content c:\temp\renameLog.txt -Value $('{0} {1} {2} {3}' -f $(Get-Date),$_.fullname,$_.name,$newName )   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, untested of course.

```
$success = 0
$failed = 0

$drivesArray = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | select -Expand Root 

foreach ($drive in $drivesArray) {
  Get-ChildItem $drive | Where-Object {
  $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:WinDir}*" -and
  $_.FullName -notlike "${Env:ProgramFiles}*"
  } | ForEach-Object {
Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  } | Where-Object {
-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -notmatch '^\.(xxx|exe|html)$' -and $_.Name -notmatch '^renameLog.txt|^renameLog_failed.txt'
  } | ForEach-Object {
    try {
    $newName = $_.FullName + '.xxx';
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName  ($_.FullName + '.xxx')  -ErrorAction Stop 
    Add-Content c:\temp\renameLog.txt -Value $('{0} {1} {2} {3}' -f $(Get-Date),$_.fullname,$_.name,$newName ) 
    $success ++  
    } catch [exception] {
        Add-Content c:\temp\renameLog_failed.txt -Value $('{0} {1} {2} {3}' -f $(Get-Date),$_.fullname,$_.name,$newName )   
        $failed ++
        $error.Clear()
    }
  }
}

 Add-Content "c:\temp\renameLog.txt" -Value $("Total: " + $success)
 Add-Content "c:\temp\renameLog_failed.txt" -Value $("Total: " + $failed)
```

Comment: great work! just needed to exclude the log files from being renamed and it works like a charm